# A better alternative to "has and will inspire..."?

Tags: tenses, synonyms

If you could rewrite the sentence

> "XYZ **has and will inspire** many people to...."

how would you do it?

The intent is XYZ has done a lot of inspiring work in past. He is still at his prime and will continue to do good work, which will further inspire people.

Comment: That's ungrammatical. Better use the full form: _`XYZ` has inspired and will inspire ..._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> XYZ will continue to be a great inspiration he has always been.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to say:

> XYZ has inspired many people to..., and will continue to inspire for
>   years to come

Answer (score 0):

Since 19xx, the classic XYZ has been inspiring many people to PDQ

... and shows no sign of stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

> He was and will [always] remain a source of inspiration for many people.